# AWS CodePipeline cross-account deployments: can't view logs because "Resource account doesn't match account parsed from ARN of pipeline stack"

Tags: aws-codepipeline

I am using AWS CDK Pipelines. I am following [this tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cdk_pipeline.html), which uses one AWS account (the "pipeline account") to deploy a CodePipeline pipeline that includes stages that deploy to other AWS accounts that trust the pipeline account. Whether the deployment succeeds or fails, I am unable to view the logs, apparently because the AWS portal doesn't like that the account number of the pipeline account doesn't match the account number of the pipeline stage account.

`ValidationError Resource account (PIPELINE_ACCOUNT_NUMBER_REDACTED) doesn't match account (PIPELINE_ACCOUNT_NUMBER_REDACTED) parsed from ARN: arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:PIPELINE_ACCOUNT_NUMBER_REDACTED:stack/test-CupidStack/ARN_REDACTED`

Successful pipeline run, which I confirmed by seeing the deployed resource after logging in under the stack account:
[image]

But I can't view the logs, which is a problem for pipeline runs that fail:
[image]

Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: I am in same boat. any fix you got?

Comment: This was happening in a monorepo folder I cobbled together from heavily-modified files from a prior `cdk init`. I eventually just gave up trying to make that work and started from scratch in a new, empty folder following [the tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cdk_pipeline.html) and got that to successfully deploy cross-account.

Comment: Actually, it worked when it was a simple stack with only the tutorial's lambda included, but I'm now getting the same error as before after adding all of my resources to the stack.

Comment: @revathi I found out that this error appears whenever I try to view the CloudFormation event logs, even when the deployment is successful. It seems to be a bug in the portal

Comment: You may find this useful: https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/codepipeline-deploy-cloudformation

Comment: @mrwnt10 - For me deployment is failing unfortunately. Like you said, i have done simple stack with a lambda and bucket and it was all good. The stack i am doing now is even more simpler - Just a bucket and a bucket policy. All i am trying to do is giving team role access to bucket in policy. This is the place where it doesnt like and tell me that 'resource account doesnt match account .. ' error. :/

Comment: @ mrwnt10- It worked for me now. I looked into non pipeline account and deleted the whole stack and ran the pipeline. all went well now.

Comment: @revathi Great, but can you view the deployment logs from your pipeline account? Or even your other acocunt? My testing revealed that my pipeline account has permissions to deploy to the other account but doesn't have permission to view the logs from that deployment. And I can't view the logs from the other account because the CodePipeline pipeline exists in my pipeline account.

Comment: @ArpitJain My pipeline account can successfully deploy resources to another account. It just can't view the cross-account deployment logs, so errors are totally opaque until I redeploy the stack under the pipeline account instead of the other account. Not a good long-term solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To view the logs of a cross-account deployment, you have to sign out of the pipeline-owning account and then sign in to the account to which the CloudFormation stack was deployed. From that account, go to CloudFormation, click on the stack, and the logs are available as "events."

Comment: yes this is what i did, Sorry, now only came back to this post. Glad that we understood. :D